# Sprint Zone turning wifi on by itself?

Tags: wi-fi, settings, sprint

lately I have had an issue with the Wifi enabling itself so I ran `adb logcat` to trace the issue. Apparently ItsOnService has been enabling it and that service I discovered is a part of Sprint Zone. I have dug through the Sprint Zone options and can't seem to figure out how to disable this. Any advice?